# Error in adding in-line type in Angular6

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular6

I got this error when i try to add the product.ts interface so that i can enable the IntelliSense in the product filter method.

I was following this certain angular+firebase tutorial and i was stubborn that the tutorial's firebase and angularfire2 version is lower than my version.

Any help would be great :)

Error

[image]

admin-products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Subscription } from '../../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  products: Product[];
  filteredProducts: any[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.subscription = this.productService.getAll()
      .subscribe(products => this.filteredProducts = this.products = products);
  }

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredProducts = (query) ?
      this.products.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : 
      this.products;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

model/product.ts

```
export interface Product {
    key: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}
```

product.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map( products => {
          return products.map( p => ({
            key: p.payload.key, ...p.payload.val()
          }))
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the rest of the properties in your interface optionals (If so, you need to set them as optional)? Looks like you are missing the rest of the properties when creating a new product

Comment: I just added the "?" in my interface and it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **getAll** method you are returning value of type **{key: string}[]**

And you are assigning that to **this.filteredProducts** and **this.products** which are of different type **Product**.

So you have to do one of the following according to your business requirement.

1. make fields other than **key** optional in **Product** interface.
2. Return value of **Product** type from  **getAll** method.

Comment: It works! Thanks :) i just added the optional "?" in my product interface.